Manejo de cookies/autorizacion entre .Net y React
Estoy haciendo un proyecto con el backend en .net y el front en React y tengo un problema al parecer al momento de autorizar el usuario.
Contexto de cómo funciona básicamente la app:
El controlador principal es "ProjectController" el cual se encarga de listar y crear proyectos, para acceder se necesita que el usuario esté autorizado.
La autenticacion se maneja con Identity.
El problema es el siguiente: Cuando hago la peticion GET a '/Project' desde httpClient, el programa devuelve correctamente los proyectos listados. Ahora, cuando lo hago desde el navegador parece que ni siquiera entra al controlador de la API ya que no imprime los logger y en el front, response.data llega vacio.
Segun lo que entiendo por lo que se ve en la pestaña 'network', parece que me está redireccionando al login y despues parece que no vuelve correctamente al /Project, pero repito, esto solo pasa haciendolo desde el navegador, utilizando httpClient y simulando la peticion todo funciona ok.
Les el codigo e imagenes de las herramientas de desarrollador por si alguien entiende cual es el problema, y si alguno tiene un proyecto de .Net-React que maneje cookies, autorizacion y autenticacion, etc.le agradeceria que me pase el repo.
/Project/Index:
  [HttpGet]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
     {
    
         if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
         {
             return Unauthorized(); 
         }
         string? userId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);

     if (userId != null)
         {

             var projects = await _appDbContext.Project
                 .Where(p => p.UserId == userId)
                 .ToListAsync();

             return Ok(projects);
         }  
     return NotFound();

     }

/Account/Login:
     [HttpPost]
     public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody]LoginDTO loginInput,string? 
     returnUrl)
     {
     _logger.LogInformation("returnUrl");
     _logger.LogInformation("returnUrl");

     _logger.LogInformation(returnUrl);

     var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(loginInput.Email, loginInput.Password, loginInput.RememberMe, false);
     if (result.Succeeded)
     {

             _logger.LogInformation("result succes");
         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) && Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl)) 
         {
             return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
         }
         else
         {
             return RedirectToAction("Index", "Project");
         }
     }
     ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
     
     return BadRequest();
 }

Projects.jsx (front):
useEffect(() => {
       
        axios.get(`https://localhost:7158/Project`, { withCredentials: true })
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            if (res.data.length <= 0) {
                return "empty"
            }
            setProjects(res.data)
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err + ' fetch error'))
    }
    , [])

network:
![img1]https://ibb.co/cQkzRv4
![img2]https://ibb.co/n8rNKxZ

Estas seguro que la autenticación es por cookies, mas parece que se enviará por u n header un token. SI fuera cookie el navegador enviaría las credenciales automáticamente. SI es un header no, y al parecer por eso no se autentica tu request.
